# StreamTransformer in Dart being skipped?

Tags: stream, dart

I'm not sure if I'm not understanding this correctly, but here's my code. I'm trying to get the `StreamTransformer` to act on the stream, but the values still come out the other end untouched.
Note: I added the `.map()` function, which does nothing, just to make sure it wasn't a missing `map` function that was my issue. I'm leaving it here just in case.

```
import 'dart:async';
void main() {
 int count = 0;
 var counterController = new StreamController();
  counterController.stream.listen((value) => print(value));

  void increment() {
    counterController.add(count++);
  }

    final transformToString =
        new StreamTransformer.fromHandlers(handleData: (number, sink) {
      if (number.runtimeType == int) {
        sink.add("The counter is at $number!");
      } else {
        sink.addError("$number is not an int!");
      }
    });

    counterController.stream.map((input) => input).transform(transformToString);
  for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
    increment();
  }
}
```

[Link to the code in DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/83af99287bab0f59d6b002fbd0ff54e0)

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned by my instructor, the transform function creates out a new stream. So I have to attach a listener to the transformed stream, I can't expect transformed values to come out of the old stream. So the modified code below works.

```
   import 'dart:async';
    void main() {
     ...

      counterController.stream.map((input) => input)
      .transform(transformToString).listen(print);

      for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){
        increment();
      }
    }
```